# Overriding 'to boolean' operator in python?

Tags: python

I'm using a class that is inherited from list as a data structure:

```
class CItem( list ) :
  pass
oItem = CItem()
oItem.m_something = 10
oItem += [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

All is perfect, but if I use my object of my class inside of an 'if', python evaluates it to False if underlying the list has no elements.  Since my class is not just list, I really want it to evaluate False only if it's None, and evaluate to True otherwise:

```
a = None
if a :
  print "this is not called, as expected"
a = CItem()
if a :
  print "and this is not called too, since CItem is empty list. How to fix it?"
```

Comment: +1 since you appear to uncover yourself another wonderful Python gem :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In 2.x: override [`__nonzero__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__). In 3.x, override [`__bool__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__bool__#object.__bool__).